# Explorer fails to load with UAC enabled

Tags: windows-7, uac

While running an InstallShield based installer, my Windows 7 machine became unresponsive.  After forcing a reboot, I can log in to the system, but explorer does not run.

I can log in as a different user without issue and when I change UAC to its lowest setting, I can log in as the user that was performing the install.  However, if I re-enable UAC, I am unable to get explorer to run again on login.

I have checked the `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run` and `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce`, but don't see anything that isn't configured to run on startup.

I completed the installation of the software as the "good" user without issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is very strange behavior. You should try to set the user to an "Administrator" if they are not already. What sort of software are you installing? It may be a corrupt user profile in that case follow the Microsoft kb and migrate the user to a new account http://support.microsoft.com/kb/811151

Good Luck

Chris

Comment: I'd also suggest running SysInternals Autoruns to see if there is anything else loading that is potentially causing this problem, perhaps it was related to the installer you ran: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902